# How do you mark a question as posted on the sandbox?

Tags: discussion, editing

I couldn't figure out how to make the needed edits to change my answer status on the sandbox to posted, and I was wondering for future reference.

Comment: I did that for you. :)

Comment: Note the for future reference part. Also, I realized it was a little of a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on the edit beneath the rest of the answer and edit in the textarea that comes up.

Like so:

> [image]

Comment: Never mind... Stupid question (somehow oblivious on the basics of questions for some reason...and I'm not a complete noob here...)

Comment: [Here you go!](http://i.imgur.com/mhnLKrc.png)

Comment: @impinball Don't be *too* hard on your self. This application is stretching tools to cover use cases not originally envisioned.